# jQuery get button classname on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to assign textbox a value on button click. I am assigning the value to previous textbox of button.
I used 
var classic = window.Event.target.class;
alert(classic);
but this gives error undefined.

How can I identify which button clicked either by class name or id or some other way.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 
    var formfield;
    var classic = window.Event.target.class;
    /* user clicks button on custom field, runs below code that opens new window */
    jQuery(classic).click(function() {
        formfield = jQuery(this).prev('input'); //The input field that will hold the uploaded file url
        tb_show('','media-upload.php?TB_iframe=true');
 
        return false;
 
    });
    //adding my custom function with Thick box close function tb_close() .
    window.old_tb_remove = window.tb_remove;
    window.tb_remove = function() {
        window.old_tb_remove(); // calls the tb_remove() of the Thickbox plugin
        formfield=null;
    };
 
    // user inserts file into post. only run custom if user started process using the above process
    // window.send_to_editor(html) is how wp would normally handle the received data
 
    window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
    window.send_to_editor = function(html){
        if (formfield) {
            fileurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
            jQuery(formfield).val(fileurl);
            tb_remove();
        } else {
            window.original_send_to_editor(html);
        }
    };
 
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'Option-Man-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'Option-Man-settings-group' ); ?>
    <div class="frame">
    <table class="form-table">
         <tr valign="top">
        <th  class="label">Logo URL:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="logo-setting" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('logo-setting') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input name="op"  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>
        </tr>
          
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Header:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="main-header" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('main-header') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Carousel-url:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="carousel-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('carousel-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Message:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="message-short" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('message-short') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Question header:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="question-cur" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('question-cur') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Happy Clients Post Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="happy-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('happy-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Happy Clients Post Header:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="happy-header" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('happy-header') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Happy Clients Post Text:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="happy-text" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('happy-text') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Solution Builder Post Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="builder-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('builder-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Solution Builder Post Header:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="builder-header" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('builder-header') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Solution Builder Post Text:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="builder-text" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('builder-text') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Agile Process Post Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="agile-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('agile-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Agile Process Post Header:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="agile-header" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('agile-header') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Agile Process Post Text:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="agile-text" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('agile-text') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Honesty Transparency Post Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="honesty-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('honesty-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Honesty Transparency Post Header:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="honesty-header" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('honesty-header') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Honesty Transparency Post Text:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="honesty-text" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('honesty-text') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Medtegra Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Client1-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('Client1-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">HDFC Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Client2-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('Client2-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">iitjobs Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Client3-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('Client3-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">ProductiveTeams.com:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Client4-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('Client4-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">JFYS Image:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Client5-image" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('Client5-image') ); ?>" /></td>
        <td><input  class="option-man button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /></td>    
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Clients Message:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Client-message" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('Client-message') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Google+:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="google" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('google') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Twitter:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="twitter" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('twitter') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Facebook:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="facebook" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('facebook') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="label">Linkedin:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="linkedin" size="45" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('linkedin') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

```
$('.form-table').on('click', 'button, input[type="button"]', function () {

    // Get the previous input
    var input = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input');

    // Get this button class
    alert($(this).attr('class'));

    // Get this button id
    alert($(this).attr('id'));


    // Your code here
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?TB_iframe=true');

    return false;

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o59eoomx/2/

Comment: alert(jQuery(this).attr('class'));
is not working. I tried with id and name also but it says undefined.

Comment: @PravinMishra If the element is not having `class` it will alert `undefined`

Comment: @PravinMishra Check updated answer. Also, check demo